# Reusable timer class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to write a timer class that I can use from different activities. This will display a countdown time in the calling activity's `TextView`.

There are examples of timers on the web but I can't find one that does this very elegantly.

Also, I can't see how to use `RunOnUiThread` from a common class; whenever I try this based on a Context I get `"Context does not contain a definition for RunOnUiThread..."`.

This is my most recent attempt:

```
public class myActivity : Activity
{
    private Timer _timer;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.myPage);

        var outputTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblTimer);
        _timer = new Timer(this, outputTextView, 2, 0, 0); // 2 hours, 0 mins, 0 secs

        // define click events now...
    }
}
```

The class:

```
public class Timer
{
    private TextView _display;
    private Context _context;

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public Timer(Context context, TextView display, int hours = 2, int minutes = 0, int seconds = 0)
    {
        _context = context;
        _display = display;
        Active = true;
        StartTimer(hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    private async void StartTimer(int hours, int mins, int secs)
    {
        while (hours > 0 && _minutes > 0 && secs > 0 & Active)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            secs -= 1;
            if(secs<0)
            {
                secs += 60;
                mins -= 1;
                if(mins<0)
                {
                    mins += 60;
                    hours -= 1;
                }
            }
            _context.RunOnUiThread(() => _display.Text = $"{hours}:{mins}:{secs}");
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate I must be doing this wrong. How should it be done?

Comment: RunOnUIThread is a method of Activity.  You need a reference to the current Activity to call it

Comment: I changed the type of `context` to `Activity` and it works now. Thanks :)